# TanStack Query v4 error at url-loader after version upgrade

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-query, tanstackreact-query

Hello after upgrading the version of package  "@tanstack/react-query": from 4.3.3 to 5.0.5 i got error at webpack that i cannot understand. The error comes from the url-loader and only shows the base64 string

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@tanstack/react-query/build/modern/index.cjs 1:0
Module parse failed: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' (1:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/url-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> export default "data:application/node;base64,InVzZSBzdHJpY3QiOwp2YXIgX19kZWZQcm9wID0
```

Comment: which bundler are you using?